# UNO - WebView Control Mixed Content Error

Tags: uno-platform

The below piece of code works fine UWP,

`<WebView Source="https://www.microsoft.com/" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" />`

but fails in WASM with the below error. Is there needs to be done differently for WASM? Is there way a UNO app can be CORS enabled to be consumed in the WebView?

```
dotnet.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost:44342/' was 
loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://[fe80::21ca:fecc:e7b9:44ae]:64237/rc'. 
This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

Answer (score 1):

The WebView control is [not yet supported on WebAssembly](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/329).